# In at the deep end, a little help tracking an event?

Tags: google-analytics

I need to track the following button press:

```
<div class="big-radio form-item col  js-brochure-fulfilment" id="fulfilment-post">
                        <input type="radio" name="brochure-type" id="brochure-post" class="" value="1"   />
                        <label for="brochure-post">
                            <span class="text">By Post</span>
                            <span class="icon icon-envelope"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

It doesn't lead to another page - therefore, am I right in assuming I add an onClick tag?

```
<div class="big-radio form-item col  js-brochure-fulfilment" id="fulfilment-post">
                        <input type="radio" onclick="_ga('send', 'event', 'buttons', 'click') name="brochure-type" id="brochure-post" class="" value="1"   />
                        <label for="brochure-post">
                            <span class="text">By Post</span>
                            <span class="icon icon-envelope"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: It's "ga", not "_ga" (_ga is the name of the cookie and the cross domain linker parameter, but the method call does not have the underscore).

Comment: ok, so to trigger the event its just: 
    
    onClick=”ga(‘send’, ‘event’, { eventCategory: ‘MyCategory’, eventAction: ‘MyAction’, eventLabel: ‘MyLabel’});”

Answer (score 0):

You got 2 error on your code
you missed one " at the end of the onclick and the object is ga not _ga, also i recomend you allways finish the script with a ;.

I tested in my test server and it's working

```
    <div class="big-radio form-item col  js-brochure-fulfilment" id="fulfilment-post">
                        <input type="radio" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'buttons', 'click');" name="brochure-type" id="brochure-post" class="" value="1"   />
                        <label for="brochure-post">
                            <span class="text">By Post</span>
                            <span class="icon icon-envelope"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
</body>
```